Laravel lockout listener doesn't trigger
Basically, I'm developing a simple user management system as my first Laravel project and I'm having some trouble with setting a listener for account lockout events.
Laravel offers a account lockout feature after too many failed login attempts, and I'm trying to store data related to that in the database. In my User table, I have a boolean account_locked column that is set as false by default, and I need to set it to true when the user is locked out after they fail to login too many times. Below are the related classes:
EventServiceProvider.php:
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;
use App\Listeners\LockoutListener;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        Failed::class => [
            FailedLoginListener::class,
        ],
        Lockout::class => [
            LockoutListener::class,
        ],
        Authenticated::class => [
            SuccessfulLoginListener::class,
        ],
    ];
}

Lockout.php:
namespace Illuminate\Auth\Events;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Lockout
{
    public $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
}

LockoutListener.php:
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;

class LockoutListener
{
    public function handle(Lockout $event): void
    {
        error_log('Lockout event triggered!');
        User::where('email', $event->request->user->email)->update(['account_locked' => true]);
    }
}

In the case of my application, since I'm using Jetstream/Fortify, the lockout is set to happen by default after 5 failed login attempts in less than a minute - and when I test said scenario, this happens:

...yet the lockout event is not triggered! I know this because as can be seen in the LockoutListener.php, I have set a console message at the handle() function, and for some reason that message does not appear in the console when the user gets locked out with the 429 HTTP error. I have done a lot of research and I have already seen people showing how to set this lockout listener - I truly don't know what I'm missing.
Version: Laravel 11.16.0 (Jetstream/Livewire)

Are you sure the handle function is not being called? Can you try using laravel logger(); method to log error? Or try to check if account_locked is being updated

You can also try using dd() inside the handle() and look for the content of the request to make sure that the LockoutListener::handle() is being called.

I don't know what that would change, but I gave these a try anyway just to be sure - still none of the log messages showed up in the console, no mather if I used error_log(), logger() or dd() - also, my account_logged column is not getting updated

I'm facing the same problem, have you found the solution @MatheusCaetanoRocha ?

In the handle method, you're trying to access $event->request->user->email. However, at the point of lockout, there might not be an authenticated user. Instead, you should access the email from the request input.
so it's look like something like this
$email = $event->request->input('email');

if ($email) {
  User::where('email', $email)->update(['account_locked' => true]);
  error_log("Account locked for email: $email");
}


Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense - I'll add that to my handle() method. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem since the handle() method is not being called on lockout to begin with. Do you think there's any missing information in this question that could help you guys? Perhaps there's something wrong in the login/route logic - since that 429 HTTP error page, I dunno.

Need some more info about your issue. Can you take a look at your .log file for more details? Also, if you're using a tool like telescope, check out the requests and events to get a better understanding of what's going on.

I don't have logging set up (I'm VERY new to Laravel) - I'll try to learn how to generate the .log and then I'll respond to this comment again with what shows up in it.
